# How can I decide the most activated spot?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

All of those are activated. And to me, those 2 that are most far from the $\ce{NO2}$ group are the major products. But, between those 2, which one will be the major? Because both of them are more separated in the same way:

[image]

Comment: (1) By "most activated", you mean "least deactivated", right? (2) Those two spots are exactly the same.

Comment: Yes, yes. So, if i put in any of those two, it will be the same result?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You shouldn't expect either position to react faster or slower than the other, because they're precisely the same.

Comment: Ortho, can you answer other thing to me? If you have a 1-nitro-3-hydroxy-benzene, which one will say what is the major product? -OH, or NO2?

Comment: The -OH obviously. Always the more activating group has a greater say in the outcome of the reaction.